# CentOS - Error parsing XML file

Tags: c, xml, encoding, centos

I need to port a C app, from RedHat (x86) to CentOS (x64). The application read an XML file, and make some database actions with.

Under RedHat, all is fine, and working as expected. But on CentOS, logs are saying that the file is'nt valid.

```
[31/01/2017 10:29:33]  -> Parsing file(file../lan/RLT_LTE.xml).

../lan/RLT_LTE.xml:1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
^
* ERREUR * Impossible to read data. The XML file isn't valid.

[31/01/2017 10:29:33] Error parsing XML file. Data won't be updated.

*** glibc detected *** fctc: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x000000000041f9f0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x75f4e)[0x7f79ffb23f4e]
fctc[0x4032dd]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)[0x7f79ffaccd5d]
fctc[0x402b99]
======= Memory map: ========
[...]
```

Of course, first, I thought it was about file charset.

```
cmd_usr:$: file -i RLT_LTE.xml
RLT_LTE.xml: application/xml; charset=utf-8
```

The file seems to be on the good charset. In my code, here is the function reading file.

```
int app_parsefile(char* xmlfile, char* xsdfile)
{
    xmlDoc *doc = NULL;
    xmlNode *root_element = NULL;
    xmlNode *cur_node = NULL;
    int res;

    doc = xmlReadFile(xmlfile, "utf-8", 0);
    if (doc == NULL)
    {
        fctc_error("Impossible to read data. The XML file isn't valid.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /*
     * Validate the file.
     */
    if (xsdfile != NULL)
    {
        if ((res = validate(doc, xsdfile)) != 0)
        {
            fctc_error("File isn't valid on XSD : %s\n", xsdfile);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    root_element = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);

    res = app_ParseTop(doc, root_element);

    xmlFreeDoc(doc);
    xmlCleanupParser();
    return res;
}
```

So the error seems to come from the line `doc = xmlReadFile(xmlfile, "utf-8", 0);`, but I have no idea how to debug/solve this issue.

Of course, I checked what doc [may possibly be](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlDoc), but without real results.
 So any help would be welcome

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to compared the tools installed on the RedHat box with the ones installed on the CentOS box? I would start with XML.

You can issue a `rpm -qa | grep xml` on the RedHat box (where from my understanding the app works just fine).

Then whatever installed xml packages you find there, try to install them on the CentOS box. Then re-run the app and see if you got rid of that error or not.

Comment: hello. Thanks for the tips. You was right, libs aren't the same at all. RedHat got a bit older libs, and some that CentOS didn't got. Unfortunally, i'm not able to install them, since I didn't got any permissions on servers.

Comment: Well you could ask someone who does have rights to install them or alternatively you could spin a free VM somewhere (like on amazon or google cloud). install CentOS and try to make it work and see exactly what libs you might need